# Find the distribution and density function of $Y = 15 + 2X. $

Tags: probability

Let X be a random variable with a distribution function given by:

$F(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
0 & \text { if } & -\infty \leq x<-2 \\
(x+2) / 4 & \text { if } & -2 \leq x \leq 2 \\
1 & \text { if } & x>2
\end{array}\right\}$

Find the distribution and density function of $Y = 15 + 2X. $

I did

$f_y(x)=P(y\leq x)=P(15+2X \leq x)=P(x \leq \frac{x-15}{2})=F_y(x)$

And this is
$F_y(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
0 & \text { if } & -\infty \leq x<11 \\
\frac{x-11}{8} & \text { if } & 11 \leq x \leq 19 \\
1 & \text { if } & x>19
\end{array}\right\}$

And then

$f_y=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
0 & \text { if } & x\in (-\infty,11) U (19,\infty) \\
\frac{1}{8} & \text { if } & 11 \leq x \leq 19 
\end{array}\right\}$

And using the distribution function of Y, calculate $P(14≤Y≤18) $

I did $F_y(18)-F_y(14)=\frac{1}{2}$

Is right?

Comment: The simplest way to do this would be to find the distribution of $2X$, and just shift the distribution of that upward by $15$.

Comment: Yes it is correct though you can simplify your working a bit by using $X = \frac{Y-15}{2}$ as change of variable.

Comment: I get $X \sim\mathsf{Unif}(-2,2), Y\sim\mathsf{Unif}(11.19),$ and $P(14 < Y < 18) = 1/2.$ [Linear CDF for $X$ implies uniform density, from there it's just linear function of uniform to get $Y]$